# FFMPEG image sequence with longer durations after generated an output video

Tags: ffmpeg, deep-learning

I'm using [this library](https://github.com/deepfakes/faceswap) to create a deepfake video. The problem is the original duration video is shorter than the generated one. Original is 35 seconds but generated is 41 seconds. Image frames captured and converted are same, 1037 frames.

I'm using this command to generate the video.

```
ffmpeg -i video-frame-%0d.png -c:v libx264 -vf "fps=25,format=yuv420p" out.mp4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1037 frames /25 fps = 41.48s`

Your video appears to be 30 fps*.

`ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i video-frame-%0d.png -c:v libx264 -vf "format=yuv420p" out.mp4`

*It may be 29.97 i.e. exactly 30000/1001 fps.